# Is or Are subject verb agreement

Tags: verbs, subjects, agreement

I have a question in subject verb agreement. Which one below is correct

Lazy riding, fast walking and long jumping are just the way of who they are.

Lazy riding, fast walking and long jumping is just the way of who they are.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many question in english stack exchange be careful someone will flag you.

Comment: The correct answer is "both". In the second case the subject is regarded as a sort of "collective" attribute, rather than being individual attributes.

Comment: The subject consists of a coordination of three noun phrases and thus requires a plural verb, i.e. "are".

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is correct.
You have two or more nouns to describe(lazy riding, fast walking, long jumping) so you need to use "are" to describe them.